# Get TranscriptFileUri from JSON Response

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services

I'm using AWS Transcribe to convert my audio files to text. I've successfully completed the transcription; now I just need to get the results.

Here's my Node.js code:

```
Transcribe.getTranscriptionJob(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.code)
    } else{
                console.log(data);
                Fs.writeFile("./myverse.txt","test", function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err)
                }
                console.log("Transcribed successfully!")
                linkit();

            })

    }
})
```

This code returns the following. How can I extract from this the `TranscriptFileUri` value? I would expect `data.TranscriptFileUri` to work, but it does not.

```
{ TranscriptionJob:
   { TranscriptionJobName: 'file1',
     TranscriptionJobStatus: 'COMPLETED',
     LanguageCode: 'en-US',
     MediaSampleRateHertz: 44100,
     MediaFormat: 'mp3',
     Media:
      { MediaFileUri: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/2+Testimonies-+Week+1.mp3' },
     Transcript:
      { TranscriptFileUri: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-transcribe-us-east-1-prod/4379/file1/asrOutput.json?X-Amz-Security-Token=secretstuff' },
     CreationTime: 2018-06-28T18:02:05.614Z,
     CompletionTime: 2018-06-28T18:06:07.077Z } }
```

Comment: Isn't it nested under the `data.TranscriptionJob.Transcript.TranscriptFileUri`?

Comment: Yes! Thank you; I was simply using data.TranscriptFileUri.

Comment: @zwer in the current version of the SDK (v3) I don't see the full transcription in the JSON response, but only the `TranscriptFileUri` Any idea why?